# About badges for recurring visits and mobile application

Tags: support, badges

About the [enthusiast](https://devops.stackexchange.com/help/badges/54/enthusiast) and [fanatic](https://devops.stackexchange.com/help/badges/55/fanatic) badges that you obtain visiting this site daily, doas anyone know if the visits made using the mobile application counts like a visit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They do according to [this meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191781/last-seen-not-updating-when-using-android-app), but not all actions with the app count, mainly just viewing the feed/question list in the app won't be counted as a visit.

Comment: Neither does just viewing the question list on the desktop - I got my counter reset at 94 because of doing that just before a long day of driving which ended past the UTC deadline :)